# copy a filtered range to 2nd row where col headings match

Tags: vba

i need to copy data from one sheet to another and paste into the next available row where the column headings match.
I am having difficulty creating the range to copy into.

this seems to be the issue - 
rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined Totals").Range(tCell.Offset(1) & lRow)

i ahve tried creating the destination to paste to using Cells and Range, but i can't seem to add variables into the syntax correctly.
What am i doing wrong?

```
Set this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPT 1 Total")

    With ws
        '~~> Find the cell which has the name
        Set sCell = .Range("A1:Z1").Find("MN")
        Set tCell = Sheets("Combined Totals").Range("A1:Z1").Find("MN")


        '~~> If the cell is found
        If Not sCell Is Nothing Then
            '~~> Get the last row in that column and check if the last row is > 1
            lRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, sCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            If lRow > 1 Then
                '~~> Set your Range
                Set rng1 = .Range(sCell.Offset(1), .Cells(lRow, sCell.Column))

               'bCell.Offset(1).Activate
               Debug.Print tCell.Address
               rng1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Combined Totals").Range(tCell.Offset(1) & lRow)
               'Cells(2, 1).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count) '



                '~~> This will give you the address
                Debug.Print rng1.Address
            End If
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: `If Not aCell Is Nothing Then` - where is `aCell` from ?

Comment: sorry my bad - i changed the variable names later. I have amended the code above. That wasn't the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2**: parameterized....

```
Sub CopyAll()

    TransferToTotals "OPT 1 Total", Array("MN", "TX", "CA")
    TransferToTotals "OPT 2 Total", Array("MN", "TX", "CA")

End Sub


Sub TransferToTotals(srcSheet As String, arrHeaders)

Dim ws As Worksheet, sCell As Range, tCell As Range, lstCell As Range
Dim wsd As Worksheet, i As Long, arrHeadings

    Set wsd = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Combined Totals")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(srcSheet)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Source sheet '" & srcSheet & "' not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For i = LBound(arrHeaders) To UBound(arrHeaders)
    With ws
        Set sCell = .Range("A1:Z1").Find(arrHeaders(i))
        Set tCell = wsd.Range("A1:Z1").Find(arrHeaders(i))

        If Not sCell Is Nothing And Not tCell Is Nothing Then
            Set lstCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, sCell.Column).End(xlUp)
            If lstCell.Row > 1 Then

                'EDIT - paste values only...
                .Range(sCell.Offset(1), lstCell).SpecialCells( _
                  xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
                wsd.Cells(Rows.Count, tCell.Column).End(xlUp) _
                         .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "Couldn't find both '" & _
                         arrHeaders(i) & "' headers"
        End If
    End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks that works perfectly. What i should have mentioned was, that i need to repeat this for several columns. (I can't do a whole block range as some sheets don't have the same columns). Is there an easy way to add other columns into this process, or do i have to copy and repaet the whole block of code?

Comment: Will all columns be copying to the same row, or will the destination columns have different amounts of data?  Are the columns in the same two sheets as your example?

Comment: haha - i should stop giving this to you piecemeal :) essentially the bigger picture is i need to take data from several sheets and create a summary sheet. There are other sheets like "OPT 1 Total" eg "OPT 2 Total"etc - all follow same naming convention. Once I have filtered the data in each, I need to copy/append the data to the lastrow of the Comined Totals, where the column names match. The data from the columns will be the same number of rows. It is just the number of columns from each sheet that will be different.

Comment: OK - that's it: any more changes you should be able to figure out ;-)

Comment: hmmm how do i make it paste values only? i have tried severla iterations with  PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues but i keep getting syntax errors

Comment: thanks, I am sure i tried that too. Must have fat fingers:) thanks for your help